# Multi-cluster MAAS and Juju

Tags: juju, maas

Have a working cluster based on MAAS 1.7.0 and juju 1.20, and am trying to add another cluster to this setup. Did the following:

1. Added a new NIC on a different subnet
2. Created a new network in MAAS that is identical to the default network except for its "IP" parameter, which is the IP of the new NIC.
3. Created a new zone, named it aptly.
4. Under cluster controller page, added a new interface, enabled DHCP and DNS, used the static address of the new NIC for "IP" and set the "Router IP" to the router which the new NIC is connected to.
   During PXE boot, new machine is able to pick up a proper IP and begins its pre-boot sequence, displays a proper route info; however, gets stuck on loading the image. Strangely, it reports that it is attempting to upload the image from router(!), i.e., http://routerip/xxx/meta-data, which obviously doesn't work.
   I could get it to work if I was to change the "Router IP" in Step 4 to the static address of the new NIC. (This; however, runs into issues during juju bootstrap.)
   Any ideas?
   Cheers,